# How to find clusters of geospatial data based on their timestamp rather than position?

Tags: python, cluster-analysis

I have a set of geospatial data with me that also has the corresponding timestamps in a separate column.

Something like this:

| Timestamp | Latitude | Longitude |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.56 | 104.57 |
| 2 | 1.57 | 105.42 |
| 4 | 1.65 | 103.32 |
| 12 | 1.76 | 101.15 |
| 14 | 1.78 | 100.45 |
| 16 | 1.80 | 99.65 |

I want to be able to cluster the data based on their timestamps rather than their distances.

So for the above example, I should obtain 2 clusters: 1 from the 1st 3 data points, and 1 from the remaining 3. I would also like to obtain the range of timestamps for each cluster is possible.

From what I've researched so far, I've only gotten either geospatial distance clustering, or time-series clustering, both of which do not sound like what I need. Are there any recommended algorithms for what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here *density-based spatial clustering of applications with noise* or shortly ***DBSCAN*** algorithm will be helpful in your case. *DBSCAN* is a **density-based clustering algorithm** which groups the *points* based on the closeness between them.

From what I understood in my quick research, DBSCAN draws a circle around its core. The circle's radius is called **epsilon**. All the points within the single circle will be counted in the same **cluster**. Larger the **epsilon**, the more points you will have in your **cluster** & vice versa.

[image]

There is more to this algorithm which you can find on [this](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/time-series-clustering-dbscan-vineet-tanna/) & [this](https://www.machinecurve.com/index.php/2020/12/09/performing-dbscan-clustering-with-python-and-scikit-learn/) links.

#### Why DBSCAN is good for *Timeseries Clustering*:

- **DBSCAN does not require k (number of clusters) as the input**

  In your case, there might be many *clusters* of time periods. Trying to fit an **elbow curve** to find the *best* number of *clusters* will be **time-consuming** & **inefficient**.

#### Code:

The below code snippet will do your task,

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Getting Data
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Timestamp' : [1,2,4,12,14,16,25,28,29],
    'Latitude' : [1.56,1.57,1.65,1.76,1.78,1.80,1.83,1.845,1.855],
    'Longitude' : [104.57,105.42,103.32,101.15,100.45,99.65,100,100.3,101.2]})

# Initializing the object
db = DBSCAN(eps=3.0, min_samples=3)

# eps = Epsilon value. Larger the epsilon, the more distant points you will catch in a single cluster.
#       Ex.  eps = 1.0 wasn't capturing the '4' value from [1,2,4] cluster. Increasing the epsilon 
#       helped in detecting that.

# min_samples = Minimum number of samples you want in your single cluster.

# Fitting the algorithm onto Timestamp column
df['Cluster'] = db.fit_predict(np.array(df['Timestamp']).reshape(-1,1))

print(f"Found {df['Cluster'].nunique()} clusters \n")
print(df)

# Plotting the Graph
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (5,5))
plt.xlabel('Latitude')
plt.ylabel('Longitude')

for data in df.groupby(df['Cluster']):
    index = data[0]
    df = data[1]
    plt.scatter(df['Latitude'], df['Longitude'], c=np.random.rand(1,len(df)),  label=f"Cluster {index}")
    
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

**OUTPUT**:

[image]

Comment: Be careful with this answer.  The calculation of distance between points and the epsilon value is not meaningful because the coordinates are in longitude and latitude which is in degrees not meters.  Try projecting data to a flat plane -- UTM, or using haversine formula/distance calculation.  Find out what projected coordinate system works best for your area of interest.